# Data branching and applying transformations

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm just getting started with data flow and I have few questions on how I can achieve branching.

Say I have a stream of words and if I want to filter all words starting by each alphabet how can I achieve it. Should I apply filter on each data and assign it to a PCollection? If so then for each filter I would be reading the entire stream of data which is not that useful and I would have to create 26 PCollections to get letters beginning with each alphabet. Is there a better way to do it without iterating over the same data?

Also if I would like to apply windowing for few alphabets and stream the rest directly how should I do it.

Thanks and appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Partition](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Partition.java) transform to partition your data into multiple sub-PCollections without having to iterate multiple times over your data.  You can then apply other transforms and windowing separately to the different outputs of Partition.

For example:

```
PCollection<Student> students = ...;
// Split students up into 10 partitions, by percentile:
PCollectionList<Student> studentsByPercentile =
    students.apply(Partition.of(10, new PartitionFn<Student>() {
        public int partitionFor(Student student, int numPartitions) {
            return student.getPercentile()  // 0..99
                 * numPartitions / 100;
        }}))
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  PCollection<Student> partition = studentsByPercentile.get(i);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It would be great if there are some sample programs.